# Dotnet build is returning different results

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, build

I have a weird issue when I'm trying to build my *.csproj after generating new unity scripts.
Let me explain the workflow.

First I'm removing all old *.csproj files from the main Unity directory.
Then I'm using following script, to generate all-new project files

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.FullName == "Packages.Rider.Editor.ProjectGeneration.ProjectGeneration")
        {
            var projectGeneration = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            type.GetMethod("Sync").Invoke(projectGeneration,null);
            EditorApplication.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Next I'm trying to build every *.csproj by cmd command: `dotnet build C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\*.csproj --force --no-restore`

This is where weird things are happening. The first run of the command is always returning many errors and warnings, but the actual number of them is different every time. The second time is reducing the number of them, and the third run usually results in no errors and just a few warnings.

I know, that I'm not getting relevant results, because warnings that should appear, are not pointed after few runs.

Here are some errors that are appearing

```
        CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\Temp\Bin\Debug\ARFoundation.dll' could not be found [C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj]
        CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\Temp\Bin\Debug\xxx_OclussionCulling.dll' could not be found [C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj]
        CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\Temp\Bin\Debug\QuickGraph.dll' could not be found [C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj]
        CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\Temp\Bin\Debug\Unity.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.dll' could not be found [C:\Projects\xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj]
```

My question is why this happens and how can I fix it? The main goal is to automate builds, but I have to build every *.csproj separately because I need to exclude some *.csproj's from the build.

Comment: From my experience, non matter what code editor you are using, Unity Editor will always build the project on its own. Even if you delete all csproj files, Unity will be fine as it builds the project for itself. When you open some script in VS for example, it will create again all missing csproj files, you can hit the build button inside VS (or Rider I suppose), but it is only for the c# scripts you have, and then when you come back to Unity Editor after some changes have been done and built in your code editor Unity will always build again form its side (considering lots of other things)

Comment: @kolodi Sorry, I haven't been precise enough. I need to create an automated build, but I need to exclude some csproj's from the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the solution some time ago. My problem was, that I didn't build projects in the correct order, which is crucial in this situation.

The valid order of project building is saved in the main *.sln file. When you want to build *.csproj files manually, you have to be aware of the correct order.